# How to insert data to a textfield that goes to an empty array and in turn displays in a label?

Tags: arrays, swift, textfield

I found this ready code that prints out an already stored array called (let dataArr = ["25","51","57","73","68"]) in rows into a label.
 I have now made a text field that can insert to another array(my array = String) I want this array  to be swaped with the first array.

But know when I swap to empty array that has already been populated via a text field it doesn’t appear in label.

I was hoping to swap the dataArr to an empty array called array that files up with data when inserted via the text field but for reason when I am doing that it doesn’t get shown in the label I am posting now to see what I am doing wrong.

But when I print the array it appears in the console but not in the label.

```
let dataArr = ["2,5","5,1","5,7"]


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .yellow
    var yPos = 90
    for i in 0..<dataArr.count {
        let element = dataArr[i]
        let labelNum = UILabel()



        let num1Nnum2 = "number 1   : \(element)"
        labelNum.text = num1Nnum2
        labelNum.textAlignment = .center
        labelNum.frame = CGRect( x:10, y:yPos, width:250, height: 80)
        yPos += 80
        self.view.addSubview(labelNum)

    }

}


var array = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    view.backgroundColor = .yellow
    var yPos = 90
    for i in 0..<array.count {
        let element = array[i]
        let labelNum = UILabel()


        let num1Nnum2 = "number 1   : \(element)"
        labelNum.text = num1Nnum2
        labelNum.textAlignment = .center
        labelNum.frame = CGRect( x:10, y:yPos, width:250, height: 80)
        yPos += 80
        self.view.addSubview(labelNum)

    }

}
```

Comment: I don’t quite understand what’s the issue...the problem is that the text is not displayed the second time? And why are there two overrides of viewdidload?

Comment: Hi Lorenzo I just posted to show the examples  I want the second example that starts with var array = [String]() to work, that's the one that you can see what inside the array when the label appears.

Answer (score 0):

Ran your code and got the following result.

[image]

Is this what you were expecting?

**UPDATE :**

Here's what whipped up.

```
lazy var myText: UITextField = {
    let input = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 300, height: 40))
    input.backgroundColor = .white
    input.placeholder = "Enter data here!"
    return input
}()

lazy var enterButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
    button.backgroundColor = .gray
    button.setTitle("ENTER", for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 11)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnEnter), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

lazy var doneButton: UIButton = {
    let button = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
    button.backgroundColor = .gray
    button.setTitle("Done", for: .normal)
    button.titleLabel?.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 11)
    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(btnDone), for: .touchUpInside)
    return button
}()

var array = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    if (!array.isEmpty) {
        view.backgroundColor = .yellow
        var yPos = 90
        for i in 0..<array.count {
            let element = array[i]
            let labelNum = UILabel()



            let num1Nnum2 = "number 1   : \(element)"
            labelNum.text = num1Nnum2
            labelNum.textAlignment = .center
            labelNum.frame = CGRect( x:10, y:yPos, width:250, height: 80)
            yPos += 80
            myText.removeFromSuperview()
            enterButton.removeFromSuperview()
            doneButton.removeFromSuperview()
            self.view.addSubview(labelNum)
        }
    }
    else
    {
        view.backgroundColor = .green
        setUpMyText()
        setUpEnterButton()
        setUpDoneButton()
    }

}

private func setUpMyText() {
    self.view.addSubview(myText)
    myText.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    myText.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    myText.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerYAnchor).isActive = true
    myText.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: myText.bounds.width).isActive = true
    myText.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: myText.bounds.height).isActive = true
}

private func setUpEnterButton() {
    self.view.addSubview(enterButton)
    enterButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    enterButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    enterButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: myText.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true

}

private func setUpDoneButton() {
    self.view.addSubview(doneButton)
    doneButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    doneButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    doneButton.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: enterButton.bottomAnchor, constant: 10).isActive = true
}

@objc fileprivate func btnEnter() {
    print(myText)
    array.append(myText.text!)
    myText.text = ""
}

@objc fileprivate func btnDone() {
    print("Done")
    self.viewDidLoad()
}
```

Comment: Hi Adam that's what a get when using the dataArr I was trying to use "var array = [String]()". I have made text field that stores arrays in  array = [String]() I want to  instead of using the dataArr to just use array instead

Comment: can't see what's wrong. Are you appending myTextIput.Text to the string array.
array.append(myTextInput.Text) and is this all on one ViewCotroller?

Comment: Thank you so much Adam just saw your response really appreciate it you are a life saviour!!! Thanks!

Comment: np. upvote would be nice. But I am curious, are you trying to do this on two viewcontrollers or one viewcontroller with two views. Also, are you doing this with or without a storyborad?

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow but how do you give, I would give 100 of 100 if know how too. I want to build this without storyboards thanks really again!!
I just had a another question I really want to have those functions the text label with uipickers in a table view cell that takes in information and passes it to an array and also so the user can press an add button that lets a new table view cell appear when pressed add.

Comment: I have built a table view that let the user add more tablecells but I now need to link them so it contains what you did. 
I am now asking if the user choses to insert information that that needs 5 tableviewcell option how can you make a button that counts all 5 tableview cells a passes all info to and array and in order to that label that we did with first option above. Regardless if it is 3 or 7 or 20 I want the function to count the rows or the cells rows and pass it to next view controller.